# parsing html text with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I realize HTML can not be parsed with regex. However, I have a string with some source code from a typical amazon web page.

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                P.when("A", "jQuery").execute(function(A, $) {
                    var pageState = A.state('ftPageState');
                    if (typeof pageState === 'undefined') {
                        pageState = {};
                    }
                    if (pageState["fast-track-message"]) {
                        pageState["fast-track-message"].stopTimer();
                    }

        <li> 48 pages</li>

                    pageState["fast-track-message"] = new fastTrackCountDown(20710,"fast-track-message");
                    A.state('ftPageState', pageState);
                });
            </script>
```

I want to grab the 48. Every number will be followed by `pages</li>`
How can I match this?

## Attempt

```
var string_tester = String(datastuff.html());
var regex_tester = string_tester.match(/\d+ pages<\/li>/);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it will always be in the list element, try this: `(<li>\s*)([0-9]+)(\s*pages\s*</li>)` (48 would be in `$2`. However, that won't accommodate number formatting. This should be generic enough: `(<li>\s*)([0-9,\.\-\(\)]+)(\s*pages\s*</li>)`. I should note that amazon has a seller and publisher API that might provide a more stable route for you to pursue depending on your use case.

Edit: I checked a few Amazon pages to see if there was a better approach to getting what you want and noticed that for the pages I checked there was no number, just this:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                P.when("A", "jQuery").execute(function(A, $) {
                    var pageState = A.state('ftPageState');
                    if (typeof pageState === 'undefined') {
                        pageState = {};
                    }
                    if (pageState["fast-track-message"]) {
                        pageState["fast-track-message"].stopTimer();
                    }
                    pageState["fast-track-message"] = new fastTrackCountDown(57592,"fast-track-message");
                    A.state('ftPageState', pageState);
                });
            </script>
```

I don't know what you are doing, but I wanted to mention that in case it invalidates an assumption you have made.

Comment: Thanks for the information. You have a good point. I ran across this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/EX_LookupbyISBN.html. So obtaining the ISBN to go through their API seems like a good route.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt was close! But returned "48 pages" instead of "48."

- If you want to match one number per query, use 
  `string_tester.match(/(\d+) pages<\/li>/)[1];`
  *note the '(' ')' captured group*
- To match multiple numbers:

```js
string_tester = "testing <li> 48 pages</li> now, and also testing <li> 52 pages</li>. see?";
regex_tester = string_tester.match(/\d+ pages<\/li>/g)
               .map(function(m){
                 return m.match(/\d+/)[0]; // or return m.replace(/\D/g, "");
               });
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = regex_tester;
```

```html
<p></p>
```